# Check for flags in Makefile

Tags: makefile, flags

How to check for flags in Makefile ? Suppose I run `make -a`, I need to be able to do certain things, How do I detect if the flag is set inside a Makefile ?

Comment: What flags do you mean? The arguments you give to the make command?

Comment: I want to be able to run `make -a` to execute certain things differently. So, I want to detect if the user ran with the `-a` flag or not. Another option is to check if some variable is set or not. But I felt flag is easier for the end user.

Comment: There's an example on the info page of exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using GNUMake, you can check `MAKEFLAGS`, like [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Testing-Flags):

```
someTarget: 
    ifneq (,$(findstring a,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
      do something
    else
      do something else
    endif
```